# Trying to get GameKit matchMaking working

Tags: swift, sprite, gamekit

Swift 5.x iOS 14

Trying to Get GameKit Matchmaking, and almost there...but... my match seems to fail with this error message?

Run GameKit on two real devices logged into different IDs.
I get the gameKit matching interface up.
Find my peer,  and invite? and get this error message ...

2021-08-26 16:29:01.361416+0200 Mutate[18060:12891141] [AXRuntimeCommon] Unknown client: FAQ
2021-08-26 16:29:01.705773+0200 FAQ[18060:12891041] [Match] Error sending dictionary {
bundleID = "ch.cqd.FAQ";
bundleVersion = 1;
isDevelopmentVersion = 1;
message = 0;
platform = 1;
shortBundleVersion = "1.0";
} to deviceID: 076731E70C32E9C1, error = Error Domain=GKDiscoveryManager Code=-1 "Peer does not exist" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Peer does not exist}

The invited one starts playing, but the one inviting get stuck waiting for a response? What am I missing?

```
    class SimpleViewController: UIViewController {
```

and

```
    extension SimpleViewController: GKMatchmakerViewControllerDelegate, GKMatchDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate, GKGameCenterControllerDelegate, GKLocalPlayerListener, GKInviteEventListener, GKTurnBasedEventListener {
```

Plus their methods...

Here is the code ...

```
class SimpleViewController: UIViewController {

  let minPlayers = 2
  let maxPlayers = 4

override func viewDidLoad() {
  super.viewDidLoad()
  
  GKLocalPlayer.local.authenticateHandler = { [self] gcAuthVC, error in
  if GKLocalPlayer.local.isAuthenticated {
    GKLocalPlayer.local.register(self)
    print("Authenticated to Game Center!")

    let request = GKMatchRequest()
    request.minPlayers = minPlayers
    request.maxPlayers = maxPlayers
    request.inviteMessage = "Mutant Anyone?"
    
    let vc = GKMatchmakerViewController(matchRequest: request)
    vc!.delegate = self
    present(vc!, animated: true)
```

This bit I am sure works... but

```
extension SimpleViewController: GKMatchmakerViewControllerDelegate, GKMatchDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate, GKGameCenterControllerDelegate, GKLocalPlayerListener, GKInviteEventListener, GKTurnBasedEventListener {


    func matchmakerViewController(_ viewController: GKMatchmakerViewController, didFind match: GKMatch) {
    self.dismiss(animated: true)
    match.delegate = self
    print("matchmakerViewController ")
    
    }

    func player(_ player: GKPlayer, didAccept invite: GKInvite)   {
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: {
        print("player ",invite)
    })
    }

    func matchmakerViewController(_ viewController: GKMatchmakerViewController, hostedPlayerDidAccept player: GKPlayer)       {
    print("matchmakerViewController")
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: {
        print("player ",player)
    })
    }

    func matchmakerViewController(_ viewController: GKMatchmakerViewController, didFindHostedPlayers players: [GKPlayer]) {
    print("matchmakerViewController")
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: {
        print("player ",players)
    })
    }

    func matchmakerViewControllerWasCancelled(_ viewController: GKMatchmakerViewController) {
    self.dismiss(animated: true)
    print("matchmakerViewControllerWasCancelled")
    }

    func matchmakerViewController(_ viewController: GKMatchmakerViewController, didFailWithError error: Error) {
    print("Matchmaker vc did fail with error: \(error.localizedDescription).")
    }

    }
```

I suspect the mistake is in here?